# Bind9 not forwarding DNS

Tags: dns, bind9

I want to use bind9 to redirect a `subdomain.domain.com` to my ip or server,
I tried doing this in `named.conf`
`zone "subdomain.domain.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 192.168.43.143;
    };
};`

and this is my named.conf.options

```
options {
directory "/var/cache/bind";

recursion yes;
dnssec-validation no;
//allow-recursion {127.0.0.1; 192.168.43.143;};

auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
listen-on-v6 { any; }; };
```

but every time I try to go to subdomain.domain.com it says timeout, or name not resolved.
my server is up and if I got my server's ip it displays what I want correctly.